# Rviz visualize only 2d shape

Tags: ros, rviz, visualization, mesh, marker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am visualizing COLLADA mesh file in rviz sending a MESH_RESOURCE marker. Every time I try to visualize the mesh I just get a 2D shape. How can I visualize a 3D object? I see a warning on rviz "fixed frame [/plan] does not exist" but everything else seems fine. I used for example the mesh package://pr2_description/meshes/base_v0/base.dae but I can see only the shape and not a full 3d image with rviz.
Best Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9895/rviz-visualize-only-2d-shape/) by [cmsoda](https://answers.ros.org/users/430/cmsoda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set the fixed_frame to a valid and connected frame_id for rviz to be able to render it in the scene.  When meshes are not connected in the tf tree, rviz only displays the outline of the mesh at the origin.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-05-16**:
If the fixed frame is the same as the published frame it will be connected.  See the rviz user guide http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/UserGuide for how to set the fixed frame

**Comment by [cmsoda](https://answers.ros.org/users/430/cmsoda/) on 2011-05-10**:
Ok, how do I set the fixed frame? In my marker I have defined in the header a frame_id="my_plane" should I set this as the fixed frame in rviz? Is this frame automatically connect?